# Conventions of grouping classes in packages

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I was always wondering which of these approaches is the best one:

1)

package: `cars.blue`
classes: `CarOne.java`, `CarTwo.java`

package: `cars.red`
classes: `CarOne.java`, `CarTwo.java`

2)

package: `cars.blue`
classes: `BlueCarOne.java`, `BlueCarTwo.java`

package: `cars.red`
classes: `RedCarOne.java`, `RedCarTwo.java`

3)

package: `cars`

classes: `BlueCarOne.java`, `BlueCarTwo.java`, `RedCarCone.java`, `RedCarTwo.java`

Approach 1 : splits the car classes into different packages.

Approach 2 : seems to be a bit overloaded since the car classes can already be distinguished by the package. But the prefix is an advantage when you just look at the class name, and no second look is needed to see where it belongs to.

Approach 3 : throws all cars in one package.

Which approach is the best one ?

Answer (score 4):

I would go with approach 3. Because all cars are in same package (all domains classes together). Debatable question and everyone may have their own interest. AFAIK there are no pre-defined conventions for these except use case based judgement.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends what you want to achieve but you should remember that package it's not only for grouping stuff. But you can also take advantage of access modifiers.

If all cars classes should have access to some method they should be in one package so potion 3 is good.

```
package cars;  
public class BlueCarOne {
  void method() {}
}

package cars;

public class BlueCarTwo {
  void method() {}
}

package cars;

public class RedCarOne {
  void method() {}
}

package cars;

public class RedCarTwo {
  void method() {}
}
```

In this case only classes from `cars` package will be able to call `method()`.

But if you want hide some implementation details between `RedCar` and `BlueCar` put them into different packages. And mark methods or fields which should be hidden as `package protected`.

Cheers,
Michal

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should create packages encapsulating functional blocks. The distinction of color doesn't really imply any functional difference, thus I would also go with option 3 here.

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1 is useful mostly when the two packages are *exclusive of each other*, i.e. in cases when the cars have a common interface, the reds and blues are compiled into separate JARs, and only one of these two JARs is present at a time. When both packages could be present, this naming is confusing.

Approaches 2 and 3 are nearly equivalent, because the names are sufficiently different from each other. Creating a separate package (approach 2) may or may not be an overkill, depending on the way the two groups of classes are used in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise I would have `model`/`pojo`/`domain` package, an do something like :

```
package model;

class Car {
    private String carColor; //Blue, Red
    private String carType;  // One, Two

    // getter and setters

}
```